# 18.04 - Not able to connect to mysql

Tags: server, apache2, mysql, database, mariadb

So I've been trying to setup my new work development system, I have gotten everything installed and setup properly except MySQL. I've been trying everything I can even think of to gain access to mysql root but nothing is working.

**Specs**

- Dell Inspiron 5575
- Ubuntu 18.04 LTS upgrades to date
- Mysql 5.7.27
- Mariadb 10.1.14

Here's what I've tried.

**Installing a fresh MySQL Installation**

- `~$ sudo apt install mysql-server mysql-client`
- This does not log any a temporary password and `/var/log/mysqld.log` is not generated.
- `~$ mysql -u root`
- `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'`
- When removing to get fresh installation
- `~$ sudo apt purge mysql-server mysql-common mysql-client`
- `~$ sudo apt autoremove mysql-server mysql-common mysql-client`

**Mysql Secure Installation**

- `~$ sudo mysql_secure_installation`
- I go through secure installation normally, reports that it tried a blank password, get asked all questions and set my root password
- `~$ mysql -u root -p`
- Type in my password
- `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'`
- Seems like it didn't properly set a password, or falsely showed that it gained access

**Mysqld Safe**

- `~$ sudo service mysql stop`
- Service stops
- `~$ sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &`
- I've gotten many different responses on this, however this is the latest one
- `mysqld_safe Directory '/var/run/mysqld' for UNIX socket file don't exists.`
- `~$ sudo mkdir -p /var/run/mysqld`
- `~$ sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &`
- `mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended`
- `~$ sudo /usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &`
- Instakill

**Mariadb**

- `~$ sudo apt install mariadb-server mariadb-client`
- `Job for mariadb.service failed because a timeout was exceeded.'
- `~$ sudo systemctl status mariadb.service`
- `mariadb.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.`
- Okay, so mariadb doesn't like me either...

What else can I try or is there some known bug that I'm being effected by right now? I feel like I'm driving myself mad trying to solve this.

**Solution**
My system requires MySQL to be run by a super user.
`$ sudo mysql -u root -p` allows me in.

**What caused this**
 - It gave me a MySQL access denied error rather than a permissions error so I couldn't tell that was the issue, however I do feel a little dumb for not trying to super user that command, simple mistakes do happen. Thank you for the marked answer for helping me out and pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try throwing a `sudo` in front of `mysql -u root -p`. I was experiencing a similar issue and ended up doing this.

If you continue running into issues with the root user I would recommend making a new user account and give it the same privileges. I did this and it cleared up a lot of my headaches. This was a helpful resource for me: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-new-user-and-grant-permissions-in-mysql